# Cant create a new path inside userid folder in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app where each user can add to his Todo List, I have a problem with folder paths. 
this is the part of reading data code was adding "child(auth.currentUser?.uid!!)" makes everything crash. without it though it works but shows information of all users with dictionary form.

```
db.child(auth.currentUser?.uid!!).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                println("The read failed")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for (i in p0.children) {
                    val notToDo: String = i.value.toString()
                    notToDos.add(notToDo)
                }
                listView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
                listView.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this@ToDoActivity,
                    R.layout.listview,
                    notToDos
                )
            }
        })
```

This is the whole code, but neither the adding part works

```
package ge.msda.firebaseauth

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_to_do.*

class ToDoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var listView: ListView
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do)

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserInfo")
        val notToDos = arrayListOf<String>()


        TodoSubmit.setOnClickListener {
            val text = TodoText.text.toString()

            db.child(auth.currentUser?.uid!!).child("ToDos").push().setValue(text).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, it.exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
            }
            TodoText.setText("")
            notToDos.clear()
        }


        db.child(auth.currentUser?.uid!!).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                println("The read failed")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for (i in p0.children) {
                    val notToDo: String = i.value.toString()
                    notToDos.add(notToDo)
                }
                listView = findViewById(R.id.listview)
                listView.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this@ToDoActivity,
                    R.layout.listview,
                    notToDos
                )
            }
        })
    }
}
```

error  tracktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ge.msda.firebaseauth, PID: 11939
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ge.msda.firebaseauth/ge.msda.firebaseauth.ToDoActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property auth has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property auth has not been initialized
        at ge.msda.firebaseauth.ToDoActivity.onCreate(ToDoActivity.kt:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
```

This is the way the database looks like and I want to add a new folder in each user named "ToDos" where I can add other items.
[image]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: db.child(auth.currentUser?.uid!!).addValueEventListener here if i remove  child(auth.currentUser?.uid!!) it works fine (but it doesnt do what i want) but with this its crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you forgot to initialize your `auth` object. To solve this, simply add the following line of code:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

Right after the following line of code:

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserInfo")
```